# Don’t recall password in iCloud on iPhone 6.

Tags: iphone

Tell me how to get another password don’t recall what I used.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple has an article stepping you through the password reset / forget procedure - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201487

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset your password by using [iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com).